# Why status is shown as failed even if there only are warnings in the pipeline steps for Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

I am working on a code repository in Azure Devops. There is pipeline setup for the repo. When I push my commit to a branch, the pipeline is triggered. After some time, I see the status next to the right of commit is shown as `Failed`:

[image]

I click and check the CICD pipeline, there is only one minor warning:

[image]

I am curious why in the commit history, the status is shown as failed. I have already searched internet, but with no luck so far.

Comment: Pipeline is likely to be unrelated to theses statuses, as they are statuses are mostly (if not only) set by external systems - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/statuses?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

Comment: what do you see if you go to details of the commit?

Comment: @YehorAndrosov If click the commit, I see two tabs: one for file changes and one for description, author info etc.

Comment: are you administrator of the project? you could try to look for integrations in Project Settings > General > Service Hooks

Comment: @YehorAndrosov I am not administrator. I will ask the administrator to see if it is because the settings in Service hooks.